# Can someone help a new guy to be good in asking questions here?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, question-quality

I would like to improve [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41415173/why-does-that-powershell-skript-produce-that-error), as it got -2 in the first five minutes. What is missing? What did I do wrong?

Comment: Maybe start by spell-checking the title? But beware that this type of "explain the code to me" question is *going* to receive downvotes. Professional programmers don't typically consider that useful, interesting, or demonstrative of research effort.

Comment: Ok, i simple guess i misunderstood that you can come to this site and ask for coding help without knowing the language, just you need a piece of code to automate something.

Comment: @Roman http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Cœur "This code doesn't work" type questions aren't on topic on Code Review, either.

Comment: @Roman: Your comment precisely nailed the issue.  This site is for programmers, not for someone who doesn't know the language at all.  And it is for learning about the language through asking questions, not for farming out coding tasks like a Mechanical Turk.

Comment: I checked a few of your older questions and noticed *none* of them have an answer ... even though they *do* seem on topic and, as far as SO questions go, rather well stated. I cannot see a reason why they didn't get any.

Comment: It is refreshing to see that a new user is asking for a way to improve his post instead of the usual posts which challenge the community to argue that their questions had nothing wrong or how it is unfair to revoke their asking privilege. Also read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (if you are asking about debugging)

Comment: Thanks for your answers.

And thanks @Cœur for completely rewrite my question.
Although i still don't get it what was wrong with mine, it seems you just changed the order of my sentences :)

Comment: @Rad Lexus Yeah, it kind of stresses me to ask questions here because i'm never sure everything is correct, so thanks for that kind words.

Comment: @Roman I did not edit your question at all. Please check the history: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41415173/revisions

Comment: The rewrite of your question was me not Cœur. There was sufficient information to answer it but the problematic file name was at the bottom in an error message. I restructured it to be more in an MCVE format so anyone can reproduce the issue by creating the file described and executing the code.

Comment: Surprised Jon Skeets' blog post on writing the perfect question was missed: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It probably is getting downvotes because it sounds like you are just throwing out a problem that you have not tried to research yourself.  It also gives off the impression that you are not too well versed in the language you are asking about.

To improve your question(s), I would recommend that you figure out exactly where your problem lies and make it so there is a clear possible answer.  As your example question stands, an answer would have to be very broad and cover multiple points.

Comment: I tried to research it myself ... but yeah, that script is far beyond my knowledge of the powershell language.

I didn't know that is a problem here.

Comment: it's nowhere written on the stack site that OP has to be `well versed in the language you are asking about` although i completely agree with you , that OP has to be specific about the issue , `why this error` is never really a good idea to start a question on SO

Comment: The basic assumption is that you have to be knowledgeable enough to understand the answers that you are given, @pavneet. No more than that is required, so you don't have to be "well-versed" *per se*, but this is a Q&A site for programmers, not a way to teach programming. If you don't know the fundamentals, you won't find it very useful.

Comment: @CodyGray that's what my point was and too well versed isn't required otherwise we gonna be seeing only 20-30 question in a day under popular tags :)

Comment: It wouldn't bother me if the volume of questions was substantially reduced...

Answer (score 28):

It doesn't look like what you provided is a minimal, complete, and verifiable example (MCVE). [Have a look at this help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which discusses how to create one.

The question is also unclear in a few places. I'm not sure what "extracts the URL of an URL link to a txt file" means. Saying that "it worked, but now doesn't work again" is also unclear. Was it working on the same file, or does it work for some files but not others? Did something change between when it worked and when it stopped working?

If you'd created an MCVE I suspect the points above would have been clarified - you'd have needed to provide us with an example file that fails and all of the necessary code, and this would have made the intention of the code and nature of the files clearer.

It's also not clear what you're asking. Are you expecting someone to explain how to fix this, or asking why the code produces the error, or asking what the error message means?

From your comments, it sounds like you wanted to just re-use some code you'd copied from elsewhere without really needing to understand it, but I'm afraid that's rarely possible, and the aim of this site isn't to help people do that. Stack Overflow is billed as being for *professional and enthusiast programmers*. If you don't know how to code or debug, or don't understand the fundamentals of a language or tool, this isn't the right place for you - yet.

Before turning to Stack Overflow again, I'd suggest you try doing some tutorials, there are plenty around. I'd also make sure that before you ask another question, you read through all of the [Help Centre section about Asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: @Peter Mortensen I for sure read through every help available to make my post really good, but it seems i didn't quite understand the help files.

But i guess in that case it's just that i didn't know that you can't just simple ask for a programming solution here. So i won't do anymore :)